# What does the brain release in anticipation of a rewards besides dopamine?

Tags: neuro-transmitters, dopamine, reward

Dopamine is released in anticipation of a reward.  Does the brain release other neurotransmitters besides dopamine in anticipation of a reward?

I'm wondering if the mere thought of a reward will trigger the release of small amounts of other neurotransmitters like endorphins.  It would help explain how dopamine would work.

Comment: To give some context, I'm wondering if in the human brain, physical actions are similar to thoughts of those actions.  If so, it would explain why addiction may occur.  If a physical action leads to pleasure, the thought of it may lead to it also.  Neural pathways to both memories.  If so, then this would explain why dopamine is involved in both anticipations of rewards as well as rewards.

Comment: Do you know what is dopamine? Why is it be? For example adrenaline is a hormon of fear, and dopamine is a hormon of why?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Maybe you can explain it to me.  Did you understand my additional comment?  I'm sorry if my comment wasn't clear.  Do you have a biology background?

Comment: Do you have a biology background - i haven't) but im sure that no one here who have it are able to answer the question why dopamine is involved, thay are mostly donno i think. mostly because thay are learn only that dopamine is involved as a fact, but without why.  but it is also interesting or me, will someone available to answer).

Comment: also you can read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine_hypothesis_of_schizophrenia

but there are lots of excessive information and specific terms, like mostly on wiki, that make text more hard to understanding

Comment: Ahaha, this eng wiki is totally useless, whatever) only find this "For example, dopamine regulates short- and long-term learning in monkeys;[138] in fruit flies, different groups of dopamine neurons mediate reward signals for short- and long-term memories"

Comment: https://www.cogneurosociety.org/series1predictionreward/ this is fifty/fifty, maybe someone can find decent post about Wolfram Schultz and his experiment. The problem, that dopamine is the key hormone to create an addiction of subject, "coding of someone behavior" when he thinking that he need something, but only he need is dopamine doze. that is why there no decent posts is hard to find. Dopamine is a hormone of reflex that called also "habit". Knowledge about dopamine is a knowledge about manipulation of subject.

Comment: i have no another idea WHY there is nothing on eng wiki about this experiment) and about Wolfram Shultz. here you can read ahaha, russian wiki, never thought that i m able to compliment it): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD#:~:text=%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%201997,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: all you need is not a love, but a dopamine.

Comment: Sorry, im writing only on broken eng.) but i still can to answer your questions by the broken eng too). Or try to use translation to russian and back to eng, maybe it helps?)

Comment: I'm sorry.  I am having difficulty understanding your comments.  Maybe, you can rewrite it in Russian, your 1st language, and then use translation software?

Comment: Although I'm a neophyte, I know a little bit about dopamine.  I was wondering if there was a link between dopamine production and pleasure (rather than the anticipation of a reward).

Comment: So, I was wondering what other neurotransmitters (and hormones) are produced during the anticipation of a reward.  I was hoping someone in neuroscience could help me.

Comment: Dopamine is a key hormon of reflex - reflex starting impulse, it is not directly reward, but it anticipates reward or punishment, any result. But what hormones are include in the current reflex is unknown, because you didn't give a direct example of the reflex. So different can be, based on reflex, and also is it psycho or physical. Physical dopamine system that manages body motions is mostly separate from the cognitive system. Body dopamine and brain dopamine are not same. Atleast because motion neurons are in the brain stem of the head brain, also are in spinal cord,

Comment: dopamine causes most other hormones to be also. it a hormon of motivation. when one create new reflex of another it can create it to connect the dopamine centers, by the repetition of the similar events - that calles training. Also an event can be just a sign that exist with the event, but that is not in event structure, like a bell for dog, or like a clock time, or like smartphone rings/signs. Also colors are used. These are all signs for dopamine system to start/stop some artificial reflex. But what is this reflex, and what kind of other hormones ll be to, based on the creator's plan

Comment: it can affect fear, or mental pain, it can be moral pleasure - adrenaline, cortisol, true dopamine or with oxytocin that is a unity "feeling", endorfine also - a relaxing. Mostly all that case emotions. Emotions are the reflexes too. Do not confuse emotion and sensitive feelings. Emotions are mostly artificial, the senses that are not "exist", but the senses are the reactions on directly things, not on fictitious something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146522/discussion-between-quietinmontana-and-).